# Why is `merit_actions` appearing in this query without being specified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

In a production Rails 4.2 app, I am seeing the following log error whenever a Events#show page is called.

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "actions" SELECT "merit_actions".* FROM "merit_actions" WHERE (actions.trackable_type = 'Comment' AND actions.trackable_id in (NULL))`

I am having trouble working out why/how this query is being created, and debugging the problem.

This query should be building an activity feed, based loosely on this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch). The Event model has a polymorphic Actionable association, through which many Comments and Photos are associated.

In the Event model is the following method

```
def action_feed
  fetch_comments    = Action.where( 'actions.trackable_type = ? AND actions.trackable_id in (?)', "Comment", self.comments.map(&:id) )
  fetch_photos      = Action.where( 'actions.trackable_type = ? AND actions.trackable_id in (?)', "Photo", self.leadings.map(&:id) )

  merged_actions  = fetch_comments | fetch_photos
  sorted_actions  = merged_actions.sort_by{ |a| a[:created_at] }.reverse
  paginated_actions = Kaminari.paginate_array( sorted_actions )
end
```

As you can see, the Action model is referenced, but there is no reference to `merit_actions` that is causing the problems in the query.

I do have the [Merit gem](https://github.com/merit-gem/merit) installed

```
class User
  has_merit   
end
```

but not on the Event model.

Why is this query referencing `merit_actions`, and how can I debug this? It is not making sense to me.

Comment: It seems your `Action` model clashes with Merit's, which is surprising because Merit's is namespaced. Try specifying the root namespace on your calls: `::Action.where ...`

Comment: @TuteC, this worked! thanks, this has been causing me headaches for some time. but I would love to understand more why this worked? Is this a problem with code in our app? or the gem? or...? Anyway, if you can post this as an answer i will select it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Action` model clashes with Merit's, which is surprising because Merit's is namespaced.

Try specifying the root namespace on your calls, like `::Action`.

If this can be fixed in merit I'll gladly release the bugfix.

Comment: Thanks @tutec, is there anything I can do to help the bug fix? Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace, so we see the offending line?

Comment: stacktrace uploaded to Gist (apologies for formatting) https://gist.github.com/ahharvey/600f3a5d2380a834703e

Comment: I don't see calls coming from merit before this exception, and seemingly the problem might be originating in `app/app/models/prerep.rb`, line 596, method `temp_action_feed`. I would assume that adding a `::` prefix there would fix this, too, or is related. I don't know why Rails would be confused, as the `Action` concept in `Merit` is namespaced. I don't think we can bugfix it there, provided what we know until now.

Comment: yes, adding the `::` prefix to `temp_action_feed` does fix this issue. As you say, strange that Rails is confusing `Action` and `merit_actions`. But at least its working for now